# how to moq a repository's where using moq

Tags: unit-testing, moq

I'm trying to unit test this simple method although I'm not sure how to stub out the where clause using moq?  I've tried the following although I'm struggling to get it working!?

I want to test that Get() method returns a list of Person.

Thanks,

**My Test**

```
[Test]
public void TempTest()
{
    // Arrange
    var list = new List<string> {"Key"};
    var mockRepository = new Mock<IBRepository>();
    var bService = new BService(mockRepository.Object);

    // ** I'm not sure about this line **
    mockRepository.Setup(x => x.Where...);

    // Act
    var result = bService.Get(list);

    // Assert
}
```

**Method to test**

```
private readonly IBRepository _repository;

public List<MyClass> Get(List<string> list)
{
    var collection = new List<MyClass>();

    foreach (var key in list)
    {
        var id = key;
        collection.AddRange(_repository.Where(x => x.SomeProperty.Equals(id)));
    }

    return list;
}
```

**IBRepository**

```
public interface IBRepository : IRepository<B, int>
{
}
```

**BRepository**

```
public class BRepository : Repository<B, int>, IBRepository, IUnitOfWorkRepository
{
    public BRepository(NHUnitOfWork<UserMapping> uow)
  : base(uow)
    {
    }
}
```

**IRepository**

```
public interface IRepository<T, TId> : INoIdRepository<T>, IReadOnlyRepository<T, TId> where T : IAggregateRoot
{
    TId Insert(T entity);

    bool TryInsert(T entity, out TId entityId);

    void DeleteById(TId id);

    void DeleteByIds(IList<TId> ids);
}
```

**Where functionality**

```
IEnumerable<T> Where(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate);
```

Comment: What is the exact type of `_repository`. Is the method `Where` an extension method from Linq, or is it an instance method of the `_repository`? What does the declaration of `Where` look like? You might be able to do something like `mockRepository.Setup(x => x.Where(It.IsAny<Func<Person, bool>>())).Returns(yourTestPersons);` but it is a pure guess until I get more info.

Comment: So does `IPersonRepository` inherit from `IEnumerable` then? If not, couldn't you create a method on the repository that calls `Where` as required, rather than surfacing LINQ calls directly on your repository? That seems like a strange thing to do

Comment: ok thanks, why is it strange?  I've also updated the question with the implementation of IPersonRepository

Comment: It looks like you're pulling back an enumeration based on `customerId`. Mocking would be trivial if you created a method on your repository that passed in the `customerId`, internally called `Where` on the collection in question and returned the result

Comment: Can you add the code in the `IPersonRepository` interface itself to your question?

Comment: see above, let me know if you need anything else..

Comment: What are you trying to test after all? Please show your test method.

Comment: The `IRepository<>` and `Repository<>` implementations as well please

Comment: updates applied, sorry for the confusion.  The Where clause is IEnumerable

Comment: I found better explanation here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60335620/how-to-create-xunit-test-for-microsoft-entityframeworkcore-3-1-method-firstordef

Answer (score 0):

I think you are leaking some implementation details from the repository interface. Your design would be more testable if you move quering to repository implementation. Here's how I would do it:

```
interface IBRepository
{
    List<MyClass> Get(List<string> idList);
}
```

With this interface you don't have to send predicates to the interface or try to mock LINQ methods (you can't mock them anyway because they are extension methods).

I guess you have a generic repository interface that you want to use. IMHO generic repository interfaces are not very useful, you can already use the common functionality by inheriting from the generic repository implementation. This makes mocking repositories really simple:

```
[Test]
public void TempTest()
{
    // Arrange
    var list = new List<string> {"Key"};
    var mockRepository = new Mock<IBRepository>();
    var bService = new BService(mockRepository.Object);

    mockRepository.Setup(x => x.Get(list)).Returns(new List<MyClass>());

    // Act
    var result = bService.Get(list);

    // Assert
}
```